# Triggering CSS animations with jQuery; Fadein() is working but bounceIn() is not?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Does `fadeIn` work differently than the other animations? In this code only `fadeIn` works, if I change them all to `fadeIn` they all work:

```
$("#mainCenterBall").click(function(){
    $("#ball1").fadeIn(1000);        
    $("#ball2").bounceIn(1000);
    $("#ball3").bounceInDown(1000);
    $("#ball4").bounceinUp(1000);
    $("#ball5").bounceIn(1000);
    $("#mainCenterBall").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: You probably have only jQuery but not jQuery UI.

Comment: Actually no JQuery UI is enabled.

Comment: Can you tell us where you found documentation about the non working functions? `fadeIn` is a jQuery method http://api.jquery.com/fadein/. `bounceIn` for example, is not http://api.jquery.com/?s=bouncein

Comment: Yeah only `bounce` exists afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how to use CSS animations and functions like `bounceIn()`, `bounceInDown()`, etc. are not part of jQuery so they can't be used with a jQuery object like that. (`fadeIn` is a valid jQuery function.)

To use CSS animations with jQuery triggering, you need to use CSS to define the animation and then use jQuery to toggle the defining class.  This demo illustrates the process:

```js
$("#mainCenterBall").click (function (){
    $("#ball1").addClass ("bounceInDown");
    $("#ball2").fadeIn (1000);
    $("#mainCenterBall").fadeOut (1000);
} );

$("#resetBtn > button").click (function (){
    $("div").removeAttr ("style");
    $("#ball1").removeClass ("bounceInDown");
} );
```

```css
/*--- CSS animation stuff ---*/
.animate2sec {
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes bounceInDownKF {
      0% { transform: translateY(-2000px); }
     40% { transform: translateY(30px); }
     80% { transform: translateY(-10px); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0); }
}
.bounceInDown {
    animation-name:     bounceInDownKF;
}

/*--- Demo setup stuff ---*/
#container { display: flex;   height: 180px;   align-items: center; }
#ball1, #ball2, #mainCenterBall {
    border:             2px solid gray;
    display:            inline-block;
    margin:             0 1.5ex;
}
#ball1, #ball2 { border-radius: 35px;   height: 70px;   width: 70px; }
#mainCenterBall {
    border-radius:      65px;
    height:             130px;
    width:              130px;
    background:         black;
    color:              white;
    display:            flex;
    align-items:        center;
    cursor:             pointer;
}
#ball1 { background:    green;}
#ball2 { background:    red;   display: none; }
.centerElm { margin:    0 auto; }
#resetBtn { width:      90%;   text-align: center; }
#resetBtn > button { cursor: pointer;   margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="animate2sec" id="ball1"></div>
    <div id="mainCenterBall"><span class="centerElm">Click me</span></div>
    <div id="ball2"></div>
</div>
<div id="resetBtn"><button>Reset</button></div>
```

---

Note that:

1. [jQuery has a **different animation interface**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
2. There's a neat [bunch of **predefined CSS** `@keyframes` and CSS styles at Animate.css on GitHub](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)